# Sharepoint integrated SSRS report data driven subscription issue:report requires user defined or default value

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, subscription

We have been running a SSRS report subscription in share point integrated mode for last 6 months.It was fine. This report had cascaded parameters which is auto populated based on user's access.For data driven subscription the user name was passed and internally other 4 access level parameter which are each a multi select parameter get populated. From last few days subscription was not going out on schedule time and below error was displayed. Even if we pass only one user from the query who has all proper access we are still getting the same issue. Also the parameter name which is displayed having no default or user defined value get changed. we have checked most of the users and they have proper access i.e value derived for each of the cascaded parameters.

```
Error: This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'XXX'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.
```

The cascading parameters are like below
AAA -> XXX->YYY->ZZZ

Earlier the error message said parameter 'YYY' was missing a value.

Answer (score 0):

As users come and go and move positions you will inevitably run into issues with their access. What I would suggest is that for each cascading parameter, have a default value that gets selected when there are no actual values available. For example, the value could be "N/A". And the report should successfully run and return no rows. You could even add a `No Rows Message` to it.